# xlrd and referenced cells (how to obtain cell cached values?)

Tags: python, linux, excel, caching, xlrd

I have been using xlrd for a while in Python, and this is the first time I face a problem like this.

I have a lot of Excel files. Some of the cells have values to data from other files that I don't have. That means that I can open the Excel file with Microsoft Excel or OpenOffice Calc and I can read the cached values, but I don't know how to read the value stored using XLRD. If click on the cell, I can see that the formula is something like:

```
='file:///media/drive/tests/Python3.5/Sandbox/kiwi/wikiWork.xlsx'#$'Rep 1'.AH6
```

But the value displayed in the cell is **'Date'**.

How can I do to retrieve the cached values of the cell without having the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the only solution for this is opening each of the Excel files and removing the links to other files. Then the cached values are stored in the file. However, it doesn't work with internal links or references to another cell in the same file.